# PrimeFaces JSF - <p:commandButton pra que serve o update e oncomplete

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando fazer uma orderList e estou tendo problema ao configurar os atributos na tag commandButton update e oncomplete. Tambem não sei qual é a função delas, mas sei que não funciona direito se não configurado certo. Alguem porderia me esclarecer? Obrigado.

```
<p:orderList value="#{cliente.listaClientes}" var="cl" controlsLocation="none" itemLabel="#{cl.nome}" itemValue="#{cl}" />
<p:commandButton value="Submit" update="displayListaClientes" oncomplete="PF('clDialog').show()" style="margin-top:5px" />
```

Comment: Em *update* você referencia os componentes que devem ser atualizados via AJAX e em *oncomplete* você especifica o javascript que deve ser executado depois da requisição AJAX ter sido completada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhando seu código vi que o 'oncomplete' esta certinho, ele vai executar essa função do primefaces para mostrar sua dialog. Quanto ao Update ele funciona quando vc precisa atualizar alguma coisa dentro da sua tela, como por exemplo atualizar seu 'form' após o clique desse botão.

```
<h:form id="form_user">
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="form_user" oncomplete="PF('clDialog').show()" style="margin-top:5px" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

O update atualiza a parte da tela em questão. 
Pode ser informado o id do componente, se o mesmo por um conteiner(como um panelGroup) atualiza todos os componentes dentro da tag em questão.

Ex ao clicar em um botão queres que atualize apenas parte da tela ao invés da tela toda. No update voce informa qual parte ou partes da tela você quer atualizar.

já o oncomplete executa algo (javascript)  quando a requisição ajax for completada.